# Composer custom release package

Tags: php, github, composer-php, release

I have a GIT repository that creates releases which can be downloaded and installed via Composer.

Those releases currently create tarball containing entire repository. Problem is that repository is huge and I do not need entire contents.

Aside from that there is a build process that compiles, merges etc. and provides a package that is much smaller.

What I would like is to upload archive that comes from build process and provide that package as download when composer asks for it.

As things stand I do not see that as a option. Even if I upload custom archive.tar.gz composer still downloads original tarball file that came from GIT tag (that huge tarball containing every single file).

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: I think that [Package](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) is what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating php class to handle `pre-package-install` event thrown by Composer.

```
<?php

namespace Company\Composer;

use Composer\Installer\PackageEvent;

require_once(__DIR__ . "/../../../vendor/autoload.php");

class EventHandler
{
    public static function prePackageInstall(PackageEvent $event)
    {
        $operation = $event->getOperation();
        $package = $operation->getPackage();
        if ($package->getName() !== 'company/repo-name') {
            return;
        }

        $distUrl = 'https://github.com/company/repo-name/releases/download/%s/archive.zip?access_token=%s';
        $package->setDistUrl(sprintf($distUrl, "v" . $package->getFullPrettyVersion(), '[GITHUB-USER-TOKEN]'));
    }
}
```

Notice `[GITHUB-USER-TOKEN]` which is needed if the package is on private repo (such as in my case).

In `composer.json`

```
"pre-package-install": [
            "Company\\Composer\\EventHandler::prePackageInstall"
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own bash or shell script that does all your dirty work. your bash script should be fired during install via composer.
Include, package installation, zip archive and upload via SCP command within your script. This will does all the stuff for you. Make sure to mention in your read me install notes, that user needs to run composer install with sudo privileges or admin right privileges.

Below are some links for reference to use shell scripts

https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

https://edmondscommerce.github.io/composer/composer-run-utility-bash-script.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for would be setting up your composer.json to be configured to use `dist` instead of `auto` for its `preferred-install`:

https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#preferred-install

Then you can create a new release with the appropriate tag in github and upload the binaries there.

PS: I havent tested this but it seems like it should work.

Comment: Thats what I first thought too but sadly it just downloads archive of entire repo.

Answer (score 0):

add into composer.json

```
"repositories": [
      {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "./laravel-package-name"
      }
 ],
```

and create new folder **laravel-package-name** with your code in project folder